# Connect Sony ILCE QX 1 to existing wifi

Tags: api, camera, wifi, sony

I have 2 Sony ILCE-QX1 cameras. I'm looking for a way to have these two cameras up and running at the same time, and to be able to communicate (= take picture, zoom in/out) to them via Sony API at same time/sequence. I've already been able to communicate to one single camera via the API, but only connected to the DIRECT-xxxxxxx Sony Wifi network.

My question is:

- Can I connect them both to one and same wifi, and a wifi that I already have setup, since I need that wifi to have Internet connection?

I'm all open to any hacks in firmware or so in order to make it all work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the QX-1 supports the "multi connection" mode
http://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1440/v1/en/contents/TP0000533738.html

Personally don't have a camera which supports multi, but in theory its just using WPS:

1. Tap the WiFi button until the display shows multi.
2. Then press the WPS button on your router.
3. Then long press the wifi button on the camera.

Repeat for second camera.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to any hacks that could make this work, but you unfortunately will not be able to have two cameras on the same wifi or connect the camera to an existing wifi. If you want information from more than one camera at the same time over different wifi networks you will have to transfer the data using a method other than wifi.